# SOLR Error in QA environment - Sitecore

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, search-engine, sitecore8

So I have a couple of search helper methods in C# which uses SOLR as the search engine. These methods return list of pages / suggestions from Sitecore. Everything works great in the local environment . But when the same is deployed to QA, This error appears in all pages where the search helpers are used.

[image]

Here is the sample search method which returns a list of pages

```cs
var practicePages = SearchHelper.GetItems(GlobalHelper.GetContextIndex(), Sitecore.Context.Language.ToString(),
                    IPractice_DetailConstants.TemplateIdString, ItemTree.Content.CGSH.Home.Practice_Landing.ItemID.ToString(), search)
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .ToList();
```

I am not sure how it is working in my local environment and not working in QA. 
Does this have anything to do with the SOLR setup ? 
I have also tried rebuilding indexes which did not solve this problem.

Comment: Can you check whether you use the same version of `SolrNet.dll` on QA server and in your local environment?

Comment: Did the config change resolve your issue?

Comment: Not really. We had multiple instances of SOLR with different versions running in QA . And we could not figure out what was causing the issue.We removed all unused versions and re installed SOLR again . This worked for us :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a configuration issue namely your `Solr Index Configrations` files within the `App_Config/Includes` folder. Perhaps `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` or similiar.

It likely works on your local environment because your local versions of the files contain configurations for how the index should deal with an `ArrayList`. Usually you see these sorts of errors when a `TypeConverter` is missing from the config. E.g. For the index to correctly convert `DateTime` this line is added to the `DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file

```xml
<converter handlesType="System.DateTime" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```

To resolve deploy the solr `config` files from your local instance to the QA environment or find the `TypeConverter` in your local config and copy it to QA.